# Como escapar comillas en php

Tags: php, php7

Necesito entregar un *JSON* en un *ECHO*, pero el problema son las comillas, ya que al inciar el *ECHO* llevan comillas simples para que no haya problemas, pero al volver a escribir las comillas simples al obtener un dato da error. ¿Qué se podría hacer?

```js
while($get_content = /*DATA*/) {

echo '
            
{
  "email": "$get_content['name']",
}
            
';

}
```

Comment: Con una barra inclinada invertida \ justo antes de la comilla.

Comment: Probaste con la sugerencia que te da @Alexis88, eso debería escapar tus comillas simples, si no tienes el resultado esperado con eso, por favor se un poco más explícito con tu problema

Comment: Prueba con `echo "{ \"email\":\"$get_content[name]\" }";` ó con `echo sprintf('{"email":"%s"}', $get_content['name']);`; aunque la respuesta de David suena mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construya un array asociativo, después use el `echo`, así:

```php
$arr = [
   "email"=> $get_content['name']
];
  
echo json_encode($arr);
```